# How can I completely disable desktop background change?

Tags: macos, desktop

I need to block the possibility for a single user to change the desktop background, or at least to make it possible only by inserting his password on OS X Lion / Mountain Lion.

I want to lock **every** possibility, from iPhoto to Safari…

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Just added a cronjob that checks for the bg and changes it if it's not wallpaper.png. Not the best solution, but works for me.

Comment: Thanks. I may be on the verge of a solution. It seems like the system is caching changes to the preference somewhere else, and doesn't look at the actual plist until it's explicitly reloaded. So if I lock the plist by setting permissions and running `chflags uchg ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist`, then change the desktop image in System Preferences, the image will change. But it will change back if I log in and log out. I'm looking for ways to force that reload (and thus generalize to other prefs) - the CFPreferences stuff in CoreFoundation looks promising, but nothing quite yet.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again @Napolux, but I've given up on my solution. How were you able to check for the background image? I was trying to get it with `defaults read com.apple.desktop Background`, but that has a few nested dictionaries. defaults isn't equipped to parse them, and I don't want to count on Plist Buddy being available. Are you getting the info another way? If you made your response the Answer to this question, I imagine it'd get some serious upvotes. ;)

Comment: I have to find out where I hide my script and let you know :P

Comment: Ha! Thanks. I think I've almost got it using grep and sed to isolate the value I'm looking for, but it'd be great if there were something cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to set the permissions on `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` to be read-only for the user.

Comment: This is proved not to work, at least on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to stop background changing.

1. Rename `/System/Library/Services/Set\ Desktop\ Picture.workflow` Change the extension. This stops right clicking a photo to set desktop picture.
2. Safari: Add 3 files in `~/Library/Safari` named
   Safari Desktop Picture.jpg
   Safari Desktop Picture.jpeg
   Safari Desktop Picture.png
   change permissions and lock the 3 files.
   Stops from changing it in Safari.
3. Firefox download menu editor and take the options out.

Comment: Forgot to add tested on 10.9.5 good luck!!